# Deleted users in search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I do a people search it still shows deleted or disabled users in the search drop down. I have tried a full sync of the AD, full search crawl and re-indexing the site but the users still remain.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to make sure.

- Make sure you have set the exclusion filter in UPA, which force UPA not to import the disable/deleted users. Please check this for more info :[HOW TO FILTER OUT DISABLED USERS](http://www.tcscblog.com/user-profile-imports-how-to-filter-out-disabled-users/)
- Now Run the full search crawl on mysites, you may need to run full crawl couple of time.
- One more thing, did you mysite clean up job running correctly? or also can you see the deleted profile in UPA using the central admin.

We had the issue and we got fix after setting up filter and couple of full crawl.